# How to use where in laravel relationships?

Tags: laravel

I have a `relationship` on `Orders` and `Customers`.

a row from `customers` table :

| customer_id | customer_name | customer_state | customer_city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amin | Yazd | Yazd |

a row from `orders` table :

| order_id | customer_id | product_id | factor_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 4 |

Now I want order rows where `customer_state` is yazd.

Order.php

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class, 'orders', 'order_id', 'customer_id');
}
```

OrdersController.php

```
$state = "Yazd";
$reportItem = Order::whereHas("customer", function ($query) use ($state) {
    $query->where('customer_state', $state)->get();
});
```

It doesn't work. How I can handle this?

Comment: *"It doesn't work."* - *What*, specifically, doesn't work about this? You need to explain your issue, including your desired outcome, what's actually happening, and any errors.

Comment: @TimLewis "It doesn't work." means the `where('customer_state', $state)` doesn;t work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from the given input you're not using the proper relation here:
The `belongsToMany` relation is used for many-to-many relations using an allocation table. But you are actually using a one-to-many relation => one customer can have many orders.
In this case you should use a `belongsTo` relation on Order Model or/and a `hasMany` relation on Customer Model:

```php
// Order.php

public function customer() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class)
}
```

```php
// Customer.php

public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put `get()` at the wrong place. 
 Change this

```
$reportItem = Order::whereHas("customer", function ($query) use ($state) {
    $query->where('customer_state', $state)->get();
});
```

To

```
$reportItem = Order::whereHas("customer", function ($query) use ($state) {
    $query->where('customer_state', $state);
})->get();
```

Learn more about [laravel relations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I did this before and the problem was not solved.